# convert pandas datetime field with NAT entries to date

Tags: pandas, python-datetime

I have a Pandas dataframe with a field that is datetime datatype.  Most of the values in the field are valid datetime values, but some are NAT.

I need to drop the time part of the datetime values for each value in the field, keeping the field as date datatype (not str).  I tried the following:

```
df['mydate'] =  df['mydate'].dt.date
```

it work fine if there is no NAT values in the column.   However, if there are NAT values, it throws this error

```
{AttributeError}Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

I tried this alternative to skip over the NAT:

df['mydate'] = [d.date if not pd.isnull(d) else None for d in df['mydate']]

but this converted the values in the column to:

```
<built-in method date of Timestamp object at 0x000002A06F6501C8>
```

Please advise how ignore or skip the NAT in the field when converting.  I'v had no luck googling for an answer, and I am trying to avoid using iterrows() looping on the entire dataframe.

Comment: please add some data to clarify the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert values to datetimes and then working nice `dt.date` function:

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({'mydate':['2015-04-04','2018-09-10', np.nan]})

df['new'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['mydate'], errors='coerce').dt.date
print (df)
       mydate         new
0  2015-04-04  2015-04-04
1  2018-09-10  2018-09-10
2         NaN         NaT
```

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate it.   This solved the problem and it is a handy note to keep.